# How do I resize hard disks on ubuntu 14.04 lts?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning

After having installed Ubuntu on to my Toshiba Satellite laptop, I realised that I had mistakenly set up the boot partitioning wrong after experiencing lagging issues. Instead of having 200gb of storage I have just under 20gb. This is the only thing spoiling my experience and I was hoping someone would know how to sort it without too much complication. I'm currently dual booting wind pre-installed Windows 8.1 with UEFI/EFI and I don't want to risk corrupting either my windows or ubuntu operating system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install and use gparted, you can resize copie or move your partition without lost your data.

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install gparted
```

or use gparted live cd/usb http://gparted.org/livecd.php